# How to create dynamic properties to a class that runs between 1 property to 10 properties?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a class at runtime without knowing the exact properties count. The number of properties ranges from 1 to 10. Is there a way to do that in C#?

I checked `ExpandoObject` buy it requires to write the name of the property. However what I'm looking for is adding properties in a for loop, some like:

```
MyDyanmicClass.Add("PropertyName" , TYPE , VALUE);
```

Comment: maybe you need a collection of objects?

Comment: Consider `Tuple` type - [From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary.

```
public Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
```

So the string is the name of the property and the object represents the property itself. Then you add your properties to the dynamic class using:

```
properties.Add("Ref", 123);
properties.Add("Description", "Underpants");
```

And get the values by casting:

```
int ref = (int)properties["Ref"];
string description = (string)properties["Description"];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class, you should have a field of type `List<Tuple<string, object>>` called `properties`, which stores the key for you to access the object, the actual object, and the type of object.

The method to add a new property would be like this:

```
public void AddNewProperty<T> (string name, T value) {
    properties.Add (Tuple.Create<string, object> (name, value));
}
```

And to retrieve the property,

```
public T Get<T> (string name) {
    var query = from tuple in properties
                where tuple.Item1 == name
                select tuple;
    var property = query.First();
    return (T)property.Item2;
}
```